# exception handling, with regards to errors raised by another object

Tags: ruby, error-handling

I have this class called `graph` that already has different `ArgumentError` raised if conditions meet. I need to implement my own class that uses `graph` as a class object. The return values of my particular method depends on the error message raised by methods inside of `graph`. For example:

if `graph` has a method named `graphMethod`:

```
def graphMethod(value)
  raise ArgumentError, "bad value, need handling" if value == 0
  raise ArgumentError, "bad value, but don't need handling" if value == 1
  #do stuff
end
```

And my class has a method named `myMethod`:

```
def myMethod
  graph = graph.new
  begin
  #notice I'm calling graphMethod multiple times
    graph.graphMethod(1)
    graph.graphMethod(0)
    graph.graphMethod(1)
  rescue ArgumentError => e
  #I only want to handle the case when 0 is passed in
    return false if e.message == "bad value, need handling"
  end

  return true #true when graphMethod raises an ArgumentError, but the value passed into graphMethod is 1
end
```

How can I interpret the error message raised by `graph` while handling only certain error messages with the same error type?

So far, I've tried to check `value` inside of `myMethod` without utilizing the error messages raised by `graphMethod`, but it's redundant, and in my actual `graph` class, the cases checked are a lot more complicated than this. I guess one way this could be done is by using `begin...rescue` everytime `graphMethod` is called, but I'm sure there are better ways.

Comment: You don't really want to use an exception here. You can return an error code and then compare that. Otherwise you have to catch the exception raised by `graphMethod` and do a string comparison on the exception message, which will break as soon as you ever change that message. Will `graphMethod` ever need to return anything later on?

Comment: I can't change anything in `graph`. Ans yes, it returns `nil`

Comment: Alright, your only option then is to check the message from the exception. You can do [something like this](https://repl.it/F76Q/0)

Comment: My issue here is, which I forgot to clarify, I may need to call `graph.graphMethod(value)` multiple times with different `value`, I only want to handle the ones with certain exceptions (in this case, if `value == 1`). I can't put them all in my `begin rescue` block b/c they may give me exceptions I don't need to catch, in which case I want my code to continue executing.

Comment: Put the begin/rescue in a function that you can reuse. Basically you'll wrap some code around `graphMethod` and call that instead. Then you can call it as much as you want and handle it however you want at any point in your app.

Comment: Why not use different exceptions based on value, `ArgumentErrorOne`, `ArgumentErrorZero`.  Then `rescue ArgumentErrorOne` and `rescue ArgumentErrorZero`.